# In gnome 3, how to let a window get focus but not on the top?

Tags: gnome, archlinux, gnome-3

Windows get focus is meaning that you can type in something in that. But at the same time, I hope that windows not to cover some others. How to config gnome 3 to implement that?

Answer (score 0):

Leaving a window in focus though not on top of the screen is quite easy in Gnome. It is possible to give each and every window a special attribut which will shift their priority on the screen.

First, right click the titlebar of the application which should always be on top. A small menu should pop up. Now just select the option "Always on top" and you are done. This option may be parsed to multiple windows. Independently of which window is in focus, the application with this attribute will always cover it.

By the way the so called "Titlebar Actions" can be configured through the gnome-tweak-tool. Under the "Windows" tab you may define what should happen on a double click, a middle click or a secondary/right-mouse click.